# What is the pre-computer version of Photoshop's blending modes?

Tags: blending

Before computers, to blend two pictures into one, I'd imagine the painter would have used some sort of mirror setup to reflect the one picture onto a mirror containing the reflection of the other picture. Does that sound right? 
What about different blending modes that Photoshop has, like "Difference," "Pin Light," etc. What are the pre-computer origins of these?

[Example of blending modes](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/blendmodesforopengl-140213092122-phpapp02/95/blend-modes-for-opengl-3-638.jpg?cb=1392283377)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Can you include an image? If it's a painting, I'm not sure why there would be any need to blend things like this...

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but any concepts like this probably didn't exist prior to computer graphics. They use some algorithm to swap and mix colors. You could make a copy of your image, like tracing, and change the colors, or swap colors during a print (pop art style), but... This isn't blending as known in traditional art.

Comment: The pre-computer version of Photoshop tools is generally darkroom tricks -- which wouldn't really apply to art as understood on this particular SE, but would be topical at [Photography.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ahem. [Cross-post](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83002/what-is-the-pre-computer-version-of-photoshops-blending-modes). [Cross-posting is frowned upon on SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted to another site and it seems to be a poor fit for our scope.

Answer (score 1):

I think the origins lie in many places. In photograms and photocompositing, each image component is *burned-in* over the initially white surface and the edges can be blended by using to *umbra* of the shadow of the hands or stencil controlling the burn.

Blending tones is an important technique in drawing with pastels. I think a lot of the blending tools come from the *color blending* realm, perhaps even more than from the *collage and photogram* realm. So even things liking mixing paints have their computer analogue, which can then be applied to edges due to the converge of the two sub-topics.